# JQuery Mobile Tabs

Tags: jquery-mobile

Does anyone know if JQuery Mobile does Tabs that stick to the bottom like the iphone native apps?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, they have tabs that stay fixed to the bottom:

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/toolbars/footer-persist-a.html

They behave slightly differently in that they disappear while scrolling and then reappear after the scrolling is finished.

Answer (score 5):

You can also watch the navbar section for more examples:

http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/toolbars/docs-navbar.html

Example code:

```
<div data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
    </ul>
</div><!-- /navbar -->
```